# Having problems with memory leaks

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimageview, alloc

I have MANY memory leaks... 
For example, I have one UIImageView that the image is flipped every time it is updated (animation is about 30fps so this image updates and flips ALOT)

```
image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image2.CGImage scale:image2.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

it is getting vast amounts of memory leaks, so I released it after I flipped it once:

```
image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image2.CGImage scale:image2.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
[image2 release];
```

but not the problem is if I ever try to run that code again the app freezes (I'm guessing you can't release something and then use it again? (Kinda new to this whole memory alloc and release stuff...

What do I do? Do I redefine the image before trying to flip it if it's been released? Thanks!

Comment: How do you know there are leaks?  Have you run Analyzer?  (One presumes this is a non-ARC app.)

Comment: This is kind of a wild guess without seeing what you're doing with `image2` afterwards, but try doing `[image2 autorelease]` instead of `release`. Or just do `[image2 release]` after you're done using it.

Comment: I ran profile in Xcode using instruments and found the leaks.

Comment: I'm re-running this code every 1/30th of a second because the image is updated to a new mirrored image every 1/30th of a second and I need to flip it again. So if I release it then update the image and run this code to try to flip it again... it has already been released and the app freezes  /:

Comment: make it like `UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image2.CGImage scale:image2.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];` your freezing problem will be resolved then, what i want to say is to define it and allocate it, withing the scope you release it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest approach is to make image2 a retained property, and then assign to `self.image2` rather than plain `image2`.  This will cause the old image to be released whenever a new value is assigned.  But you would then need to add an `autorelease` call to your `[UIImage alloc] init...` call to release the retain done by the `alloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You're making it unnecessarily confusing by reusing the same variable name. Add a temporary variable.

```
UIImage* image; // assuming you set this up earlier, and that it's retained
UIImage* flippedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
// Now we're done with the old image. Release it, so it doesn't leak.
[image release];
// And set the variable "image" to be the new, flipped image:
image = flippedImage;
```

Comment: Okay but if I need to run that code again 1/30th of a sec on later when the image is updated to a new flipped image and I need to flip it again will this freeze because I've already released it?

Comment: Or does redefining it (with the asterisk) act like an "un-release" if you will?

Comment: If you are doing exactly this code to `image`, over and over, then it should work fine.  Before the code runs, `image` points to a retained UIImage. After the code runs, `image` points to a different retained UIImage, and the old image is gone.

Comment: (It's incredibly inefficient of course, but fixing that is not what you are asking about here. And your question about "un-release" is just nonsensical -- whatever train of thought you were on, it's the wrong one.)

Comment: I'm checking to see if it works the way I'm hoping it does now haha!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the image view's `image` property to the resulting image, *then* release the allocated image.  For example:

```
image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image2.CGImage scale:image2.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
self.someImageView.image = image2;
[image2 release];
```

Alternately, you could just autorelease the returned image.  Like so:

```
image2 = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image2.CGImage scale:image2.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored] autorelease];
self.someImageView.image = image2;
```

---

Edit: after you clarified what you were asking, here's a better way to flip your image vertically.

```
//lets suppose your image is already set on the image view
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);
```

then when you want to change it back to normal:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Comment: Okay but if I need to then do this again 1/30th of a second later and the image is already released how can I do it again?

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what you're doing. Actually your code makes no sense.  Why are you setting `image2` to the same image (`image2`) that it already is?  Are you mirroring the image or something?  Probably not the most optimized way to do this.  Have you ever thought about using transforms instead?

Comment: I'm setting it to itself but mirrored... right now the current image2 is upside down, so I'm reorienting it. But I have to use that code, that reorients it, every time the image is updated to a new image (which is every 1/30th of a second) So if I release it then update the image then try to reorient it all over again the app freezes and quits.

Comment: Well, you could always use a retained property like `Hot Licks` pointed out below.  But in your case I would try to look into transforming the image instead of reallocating it 30 times per second. That's a recipe for a major slowdown.